# Pre Compiled Views in ASP.NET MVC & JS files

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, telerik, precompiled

We are using plug-in approach for module development in asp.net MVC. We use pre compiled view approach for each module and is added as separate web project and referred by main web project. only main web project is deployed in IIS.

My Question - all modules are using TELERIK (kendo UI) for UI development so I have to keep same js and css files in each modules. can I keep them at one place and all projects of my solution can refer it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add them via a NuGet package in each module? That way Kendo UI isn't in your version control at all and is fetched on build.

https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Kendo+UI

Or refer to the files on a CDN from within each module?

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/cdn

Comment: we are working on secure application so we may not have internet where we will deploy our app. basically it will be run in closed network

Comment: I want to that it should be at one place so if there in any upgrade then we have to do it at one place not in each module. can we place them at one place and refer by all modules?

Comment: You could have the files in one place and add them to each Module as links, then copy them into each module on build. http://mattperdeck.com/post/Copying-linked-content-files-at-each-build-using-MSBuild.aspx